# How can I using method filter search in API REST of SAILJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, sails.js

Hi I have problem when I want generate api rest in sailjs
here code for generation api rest :

```
sails generate api dentist
```

that will be generate path url like `/create` , `/update`, `/destroy` , and `/dentist`

my question is inside path `/dentish` i get list of all row in my table, but how can I custom that by get row using filter( adding condition ) ?

Note:
I cant found documentation about Rest API in sailjs site , is will be helpfull if any documentation for this.

Comment: did my answer help you? Please notify me and I will follow trying help you

Answer (score 1):

You could use parameters in your request. So, when you send a GET request to `/dentish` you receive all rows in table. But, if you send a GET request `/dentish` with `?id=5` you can get only the element that match the ID. To get this you have to program it explicitly, because you actually only have one endpoint, `/dentish`.

**config/routes.js**

```
'GET /dentish' : {controller : "Example", action: "get"},
```

**api/ExampleController.js**

```
get : function(req, res){

    // Initialize filters as empty JSON
    var filters = {};

    // If the parameter key has been sent with the request...
    if (req.param("key") != "undefined"){

        // ... we store the key with its value in the filters JSON
        filters["key"] = req.param("key");
    }

    // We have built our filters, we send the query...
    Model.find(filters).exec(function(err,resuls){

         // ...and show results
         console.log(results)
    });
}
```

Comment: ok i understant that, did u know where location file after sails `generate api dentist` ?

Comment: if you mean locale file where translations are defined, you can find it at `config/locales/`. In this folder, you will find a four json files, one for each one of this languages: Spanish, English, French and Deutsch.  At `config/i18n.js` you can set some locale parameters.

Comment: i think that was not  i mean because i am not talking language, when i hit  `generate api dentist` this should be gnerate mvc file too, but where location of this file ?